# Load control in the send queue with Django + Celery

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm developing an application with Django and Celery to manage the send queues. I would like to apply a charge control for each broker receiving the messages. I could make an appointment to the main DB to determine which broker received more messages in the period, but I think it's compromising application performance.

The system processes send queues requests through the Celery. These requests are sent to several different servers. I would like to balance the sending of messages by the server, so that all receive about the same amount of requests.

Anyone have any suggestions or believe that using the main DB I will not miss the performance because of the numerous consultations?

Comment: Can you describe what problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @scytale The system processes send queues requests through the Celery. These requests are sent to several different servers. I would like to balance the sending of messages by the server, so that all receive about the same amount of requests.

Comment: can you update your question with that information please